# error when joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, derby

Query :

```
select i.Name,ri.Country,ri.State,ri.City 
from Information as i
join ResidenceInformation as ri
order by Name
```

The error that i get is :

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "order" at line 4, column 5.
Line 1, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.
```

Why am i getting an error ?

Comment: derbi that comes with netbeans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you forgot to specify JOIN criteria, like this:

```
  SELECT i.Name, ri.Country, ri.State, ri.City 
    FROM Information as i
    JOIN ResidenceInformation as ri ON ri.column = i.column
ORDER BY Name
```

You need to replace `column` with the names of the appropriate columns that link the tables correctly for the output you need.

You should also specify the table alias in your `ORDER BY`, to protect against an ambiguous column reference error.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because your syntax is wrong: after `join` there needs to be `on`, like this:

```
select i.Name,ri.Country,ri.State,ri.City 
from Information as i
join ResidenceInformation as ri
  on ri.info_id=i.id -- <<< Added a join condition
order by Name
```

SQL needs to know how to "link up" the rows of the table that you are joining to the row(s) of the other table(s) in the query. I am assuming that `ResidenceInformation` has a foreign key into `Information` called `info_id`.

If the `Name` is present in *both* `ResidenceInformation` and `Information`, you need to prefix it with the table name or an alias. In fact, it's a good idea to do it anyway for added clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgot to tell the join clause which columns to join against. You need to tell the database how these 2 tables connect to each other. Something like **`ON i.id = ri.InformationId`**

```
select i.Name,ri.Country,ri.State,ri.City 
from Information as i
join ResidenceInformation as ri ON i.id = ri.InformationId
order by i.Name
```

Also, you may need the table alias in the `order by` clause, which I've added as well.